# Is "it is" a phrase or a clause?

Tags: word-usage, phrases, clauses

Is "it is" considered a phrase or a clause? What is the reason?

Comment: Have you looked at the dictionary definitions of 'phrase' and 'clause'?

Comment: The question should be "**Is** 'it is' considered...?" because we say "X *is* considered Y" not "X *does* considered Y".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a clause.

A clause consists of a subject, a verb, and zero or more dependent phrases, such as objects, adverbial phrases and many more. A clause is centred around a verb, thouhg in some clauses the subject or even the verb might be implied and not explicitly present.

That makes the very short sentence "It is." a clause.  There is a subject "it" and verb "is".

Phrases, by contrast are not headed by verbs.  For example "a happy dog" is a noun phrase. It is headed by the noun "dog".

To take this further, consider, "a cat that is happy". It is a noun phrase.  It is headed by the noun "cat".  The clause "is happy" is a relative clause and a subordinate part of the noun phrase. The word "that" marks this subordinate relative clause.  This phrase contains a clause